# Multiple aruments in re.search (python)

Tags: python, regex

I need some help with re.search() function. I have this piece of code:

```
login_redirect = re.search("'loginForm', 'false', '(.*?)'", login_page).group(1)
```

And it doesn't work, although login_page has multiple 'loginform' pieces. I know how re.search() works in general, but I don't know what all that stuff in the first argument does. If somebody would explain it, I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Please show us the input in question (stripped down to the relevant part), the regexp itself, the expected output and the observed output.

Comment: Are you parsing XML/HTML? Because regexes are not the right tool for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.